# Объяснить как работает Aссоциативный массив

Tags: php, массивы

> `Объяснить как работает эта часть кода`.

`$result[$item['country']][] = $item['city'];// не понимаю зачем тут []`

```
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $result[$item['country']][] = $item['city'];
    }
```

> `Пример Aссоциативного массива`

```
$cites = [
        [
            'country' => 'Россия',
            'city' =>    'Москва',
        ],
        [
            'country' => 'Беларусь',
            'city' =>    'Минск',
        ],
        [
            'country' => 'Россия',
            'city' =>    'Питер',
        ],
        [
            'country' => 'Россия',
            'city' =>    'Владивосток',
        ],
        [
            'country' => 'Украина',
            'city' =>    'Львов',
        ],
        [
            'country' => 'Беларусь',
            'city' =>    'Могилев',
        ],
        [
            'country' => 'Украина',
            'city' =>    'Киев',
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: Пустые скобки - это push, насколько я знаю.

Comment: Т.к. мы хз под каким индексом нам добавлять новый элемент, мы используем пустые скобки, что в условиях цикла будет давать +1 к индексу, начиная с 0, т.е. 0, 1, 2, и т.д. Как сказал @Qwertiy это push из js (а может и еще откуда)

Comment: Можете спокойно избежать `[]`, если в цикле напишите так `foreach($cities as $key => $item)`, в `$key` будет попадать идекс перебираемого элемента, т.е. в вашем случае города. Ну и соответственно избавиться от добавления нового элемента через алокацию нового значения в массиве (push по факту) `[]`, написав так: `$result[$item['country']][$key] = $item['city'];`. Таким образом, вы еще и сохраните ключи из изначального массива, под которыми были города (иногда очень полезно).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь в конечном итоге получится ассоциативный массив, где ключом является название страны, а значением — массив городов этой страны

Предположим, вы на самой первой итерации цикла и рассматриваете элемент `['country' => 'Россия', 'city' => 'Москва']`.

Строка

```
$result[$item['country']][] = $item['city'];
```

будет означать

```
$result['Россия'][] = 'Москва';
```

Если в начале `$result` не имеет никакого значения, то переменная станет ассоциативным массивом с единственным элементом. Ключом будет `'Россия'`.

Значение в начале у элемента отсутствует, но, поскольку мы применяем к нему оператор `[]`, который означает *добавить в самый конец массива*, то значением станет пустой массив, в который будет добавлен элемент `'Москва'`.

```
$result = [
  'Россия' => [ 'Москва' ]
];
```

После завершения цикла у нас получится ассоциативный массив со странами и городами.